# jQuery get parent optgroup

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

I'd like to detect if the selection option is under the 'international' optgroup. Right now my approach is to detect the closest optgroup from the selected item, and get the contents of its label attribute. I could test that string for the word 'international'. Other approaches are more then welcome.

As you can tell, from this markup its unfortunate that the optgroup doesn't wrap the child options:

```
<select id="venue">
    <optgroup label="New England"></optgroup>
        <option value="1">&nbsp;NH</option>
        <option value="2">&nbsp;ME</option>
        <option value="3">&nbsp;VT</option>
        <option value="4">&nbsp;MA</option>   
        <option value="4">&nbsp;CT</option>   
        <option value="4">&nbsp;RI</option>   
    <optgroup label="International"></optgroup>
        <option value="100">Canada</option>
        <option value="100">Texas</option>
        <option value="100">Mexico</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery I've been working with obviously wont work, but you can see where I am trying to get to:

```
dropdownval = jQuery('select#venue option:selected')
    .parentsUntil( jQuery('optgroup'), '[label*="international"]')
        .attr('label');`
```

**EDIT**

Its been pointed out to me that the following nesting of optgroups is also possible

```
<select id="venue">
    <optgroup label="New England"></optgroup>
        <option value="1">&nbsp;NH</option>
        <option value="2">&nbsp;ME</option>
        <option value="3">&nbsp;VT</option>
        <option value="4">&nbsp;MA</option>   
        <option value="4">&nbsp;CT</option>   
        <option value="4">&nbsp;RI</option>   
    <optgroup label="International"></optgroup>
        <option value="100">&nbsp;Canada</option>
        <option value="100">&nbsp;Texas</option>
        <option value="100">&nbsp;Mexico</option>
    <optgroup label="&nbsp;Europe"></optgroup>
        <option value="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;Bruges</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `.prevUntil` is what you need, not `.parentsUntil`, since the optgroup is not a parent.

Comment: good shout, but `dropdownval` still returns as `undefined`

Comment: I didn't realize `prevUntil` stops _before_ the matched element, not including it. See my answer.

Comment: If you want nesting like as in your edit, you really need to wrap the optgroups around what they contain. How else can you tell that Europe is a sub-category rather than a main category?

Comment: Its a very good point, and a shortcoming of the way the dropdown markup is generated. I guess I could start counting the number of `&nbsp;` that appear *kidding*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is dependably ordered (as presented), then you can skip catching the relationship, ie `first()`, etc, and follow `.prevAll('optgroup')` all the way up. But if the order of your `option`s might change, try `.nextAll('optgroup')`, or follow @Barmar's logic to traverse in the direction needed:

```
$("#venue").change(function() {
    $("#venue option:selected").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prevAll('optgroup').attr('label') == 'International') {
            alert('detected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ibIJezO/1/

Comment: yeah, jsfiddle is down, I went to jsbin

Comment: Your answer worked on my test case, however I've discoved that further nesting into subcatagories is actually likely. I'd take your answer as correct as it solved my OP but if you have any thoughts these different conditions I'd appreciate them.

Comment: .prevAll() and .nextAll() can move up and down, and then you'll need to use something like .children() to drill down into those selected levels. You can learn about 'Tree Traversal' with jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ - these concepts applied with the answers above should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#venue option:selected').prevAll('optgroup').first().is('[label*="International"]'))
    ...
}
```

`.prevAll('optgroup')` gets all the preceding `optgroup`s. `.first` restricts it to the first one, which is the closest preceding `optgroup`. Then `.is()` tells you if its label matches your criteria.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aQeCAG/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wasn't aware of `.is()` to modify the query into a bollian - that's going to be quite usefull - thanks again.